# How to pass/obtain app_state* via JNI?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

how to pass/obtain the app_state* via JNI?

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_ui_MainActivity_InitializeMainloop(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject obj)
{
   ...
   MyApplication Application(pState) // pState is of type app_state*
   ...
}
```

**Background**:

I want to create a game engine based application that accesses the sensors of the smartphone via ndk, however, my main entry point of the Android application 'MainActivity' is written in Java.
In order to reduce battery consumption I need to be able to constrain my native application when the Android application is closed/paused/resumed.
One way to do that would be by wrapping respective JNI functions from within the 'MainActivity' and pass the information that way into the native application. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your suggestion sounds like a straightforward solution to me. That's what I would do. I can't think of anything simpler or more efficient.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your reply. I thought so, will do :)!